# Unable to use istream in a cpp object and header file

Tags: c++, object, istream

Header file

```
#ifndef IREADER_H
#define IREADER_H
#include <iostream>


class iReader {
public:
    iReader();
    iReader(istream *input);
    iReader(const iReader& orig);
    virtual ~iReader();
private:
    Pixel *pixelData;
    char *cData;
    istream *input;
};

#endif  /* IREADER_H */
```

.cpp File

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Pixel.h"
#include "iReader.h"

iReader::iReader() {

}

iReader::iReader(istream *input){

}

iReader::iReader(const iReader& orig) {
}

iReader::~iReader() {
}
```

(sorry if i didn't copy the code in correctly)

So this is my code. I'm making a new object and I just was to be able to pass in an istream pointer, and have an istream pointer variable. It errors in netbeans saying, "Unable to resolve identifier istream". It works fine in my main file, but not in this object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably using `using namespace std;` in your main file.

You need to qualify `istream`:

```
#ifndef IREADER_H
#define IREADER_H
#include <iostream>
class Pixel; // <--- you should also forward declare Pixel
class iReader {
public:
    iReader();
    iReader(std::istream *input);
    iReader(const iReader& orig);
    virtual ~iReader();
private:
    Pixel *pixelData;
    char *cData;
    std::istream *input;
};

#endif  /* IREADER_H */
```

Comment: oh, haha. That is obvious. Thank you!